# Rails: Query database for users with specific time value while respect individual users time zone setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

I have a background job that runs every 15 minutes and generates reminder emails. I would like to create a query that returns all users who have a specific time saved and respect how their timezone setting effects that time.

So I have a `User` model that stores:

- `:time`: a users reminder time, eg `17:00:00`
- `:string`: their timezone, eg `EST`

So if the job runs at `17:00:00` EST, it will return users whose settings are:

- `reminder_time: 17:00:00`, `time_zone: EST`
- `reminder_time: 13:00:00`, `time_zone: PST`

What is the best way to build that query? Can it be done in one pass, relying on Postgres to handle the work? Do I have to stagger it, group by each time zone and doing the math for each on in Ruby?

I currently have this setup as an `ActiveRecord` scope that doesn't consider timezones, and I am trying to add that consideration now.

```
scope :receives_reminder_at, -> (time) do
  ready.where(reminder_time: time)
end
```

Comment: just store the reminder_time in UTC, this way you don't have to worry about the TZ when querying, since they will all be normalized to UTC. (assuming you are running your servers UTC. it will just work as expected).  Then you just use their TZ offset in order adjust the time for their viewing?

Comment: I was just about to write that as an answer after talking to a buddy of mine. Put that as an answer below and I'll make sure to mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with users in multiple timezones, it is normally easiest to standardize on UTC.

So store the reminder_time in UTC, this way you don't have to worry about the TZ when querying, since they will all be normalized to UTC. (assuming you are running your servers UTC. it will just work as expected). Then you just use their TZ offset in order adjust the time for their viewing.

Comment: Actually it's wrong answer (not acceptable for everyone). There are many timezones which have daylight saving time and theyl have different utc offset on summer and winter time. For example. User have winter utc offset +4 hours. And want to be reminded at 06:00. You save reminder time 02:00 in utc. But in summer this timezone has utc offset +3 hours. So in summer user will get reminder in 05:00 instead 06:00.

Comment: if you store the user's Timezone, that will contain their offsets for Both Daylight and Standard, and based on the day you are looking at use the correct offset (Assuming that you are keeping the tz / zoneinfo files updated on your server/app).  You just don't store something like -0500, you Store something like `America/New_York` (or maybe `US/Eastern` which links to it).   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select on User model. Something like:

```
User.select{|user| user.time == time_the_job_runs.in_time_zone(user.string)}
```

You should replace the "time_the_job_runs".  It didn't got clear for me how to get it. But the `in_time_zone` method should be the one you're looking for to convert time based on a timezone string. Hope it helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just met same problem. And found article how to make it, just how to think solve it myself. But with ready code. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-case-study-in-multiple-time-zones

Main idea is to:

1. At first you find timezones which have specific time now.

   ```
   module ActiveSupport
     class TimeZone
       def self.current_zones(hour)
         all.select { |zone|
           t = Time.current.in_time_zone(zone)
           t.hour == hour
         }.map(&:tzinfo).map(&:name)
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. You find users with this timezone.

   ```
   User.where(zone: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.current_zones(hour)).where(options)
   ```